# How to change ModalBottomSheet border and height?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a custom modal that's allow me to set height and borders, I already have this.

**home.dart**

```
body: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(child: Text('Open'), onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return HomeModal();
      });
    }),
  ),
```

**home_modal.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
    child: Container(
      height: 800.0,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I already tried with container to

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300.0,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
          )),
    );
  }
```

**Current Behavior**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the corner of your ModalBottomSheet rounded, you need to set the canvasColor of your MaterialApp widget to transparent.

```
return new MaterialApp(
  theme: new ThemeData(
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  home: HomePage(),
);
```

To set the height of your ModalBottomSheet, you need to set the height of your Container widget to your desired value.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
    child: Container(
      height: ####, // your desired height here
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: new Text("Hi modal sheet"),
      ),
    ),
 );
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to change the bottom sheet's border. You should use MaterialApp as your parent widget and set a ThemeData object to its theme property. The ThemeData should override the bottomSheetTheme like this: bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)))

Answer (score 3):

Use following in your `RaisedButton`'s `onPressed()` method.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100, // enter any height of your choice
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: YOUR_WIDGET,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, can I increase the height to more the half of my view?

Comment: For that you need to change the source file. Not a good way. Modal bottom sheet comes from Material design. and has got a fixed max height.

Comment: Can you please give me a slice of code, to how properly do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
 isScrollControlled: true,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100, // enter any height of your choice
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: YOUR_WIDGET,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).